# wifi can not get ip address on automatic

Tags: windows-xp

My wifi can not get ip address if set on automatic on my desktop with winsows-xp sp2. I have tried 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.8 all work well giving status " connected and signal strength excellent, but no browsing then.

Can any body guide me what to do ?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, Asad. Can you try to give some more detail to your question by answering these questions.
1. How are you checking that it is not automatically getting an address? Is there an error message?
2. When you write "no browsing then", do you mean not able to browse the network or not able to browse the Internet?

Comment: Thanks Charlie, When I log on to my network, the icon below for wireless connection gives warning status "searching ip address" and signal strength "excellent." As soon as I give ip address manually it immediately locks to network giving status "Connected." but not able to browse the Internet

Comment: Just because you can connect by giving a static IP does not mean there is a gateway to the Internet. Sounds like the router is not setup correctly. Do you have access to the router you are attached to? Do you know if other computers or devices can connect to it and obtain an IP automatically?

Comment: Yes Charlie I have router access and can connect my desk top by cable. yes my other lap top in home is connected to it via wireless and its working perfectly without any issue. thanks

Comment: My ADSL Router company is Telecom, Model Mega 105WR

Comment: The first thing I would do it connect the laptop using a lan cable and install SP3.  You can worry about the wireless problem after its secure.

Answer (score 0):

By the comments above, it seems to be this computer is the issue since other devices work properly when connecting to the router. Here are two things to try;

1. Open Network Connections and right click on the wireless connection in question, then choose repair. If that fails or does not fix the issue the TCP/IP stack probably needs to be reset.
2. Reset TCP/IP; [How to reset Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=299357)

Comment: 1- failed., 2- run fix it for me, result same as before. my desktop is Compaq hp D530

Answer (score 0):

- In *Run…* type `services.msc`.
- Restart the *DHCP Service*  and *DHCP Client*.
- Shut down your PC and router both for 15–20 minutes.

It should work fine.

Comment: what about `ipconfig /renew` ?